# VS Code - Bring back the sidebar with project files after search

Tags: visual-studio-code

Once I search or install new plugin in VS Code, I want to see my project folders on the sidebar back again. But I can't find a way to see my Project files and folders on the sidebar again.

This is the screenshot of me installing a new plugin. How do i get my project folders back into the sidebar?

[image]

Comment: Or show the Activity Bar where both those icons live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl+Shift+E`,

Or in `View` menu, find `Explorer`

Comment: Got it. Cmd+Shift+E on mac